# DatePicker padding all wrong

Tags: android, datepicker, padding

I have a DatePicker limited to the width shown below. For some glorious reason, the year wheel is half obscured, while the month/day wheels have over double the padding they need. How can I adjust the paddings to allow full visibility of wheels?

[image: datepicker layout]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/date"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/labelMargin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/labelMargin"
        android:text="Date*"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"/>
    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateLabel"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateLabel"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner">
    </DatePicker>
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you using a custom theme? Could you show us the code you're using to set the padding for the elements?

Comment: @peace right, edited

Comment: If you remove the label does it format the way you want it to?

Comment: Well, it expands to max width if I remove the label and width constraints, but I want it to stay the current width. I just want to make room for the year by narrowing the other spinners